# ChatGPT API Key Not Working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, api-key, openai-api

I have installed the ChatGPT:Genie and CodeGPT libraries in Visual Studio Code. However, when I try to enter the API key from within VS Code, it is not being accepted. What steps should I take to resolve this issue?

CodeGPT Output: Enter your API KEY to save it securely.

Note: by using palette API key removed + VS Code restart
[image]

Comment: Same for me, getting same message and chat refuses to work

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely your desktop environment isn't recognized correctly. So VS Code cannot use the correct OS keyring.

I had this problem with Fluxbox.

At first I found as workaround that launching my DE with the command:

```
sudo systemctl start display-manager.service
```

made VS Code (codium in my case) work as expected, i.e. the API key was asked only once.

But the real solution with explanation is here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_troubleshooting-keychain-issues

Long story short, I added

```
  "password-store":"kwallet5"
```

in ~/.vscode-oss/argv.json

Please check the linked documentation for the supported values, YMMV.